# Spring Layered Fat Jar and Gradle Plugin layertools jarmode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

Spring boot 2.3.0 has the layered fat jars which are optimized for container image builds. Now, the Spring documentation discusses only Maven build tool, and not Gradle.

Please, what do we need to do to the Gradle plugin to allow it to build a "layered jar" for spring boot?

For example: if extracting a jar with the command `java -Djarmode=layertools -jar app.jar extract` which has been made with Gradle Spring boot plugin `id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.0.RELEASE"` it fails with message: `Unsupported jarmode 'layertools'`. Basically if the jar has been built with `./gradlew bootJar` it seems layered jar is not active by default.

Extracting a layered jar should result in the following directories, and these are then copied into another container image for execution, and only if lower layers have changed does the caching system have to re-read them. Layered jar extracted with `-Djarmode=layertools` flag:

```
./dependencies/
./snapshot-dependencies/
./resources/
./application/
```

The blog at spring [Spring Blog 2.3.0.ML](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1) discusses Maven build tool and the configuration:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <layout>LAYERED_JAR</layout>
</configuration>
```

How do we enable the same configuration for Gradle plugin?

Comment: Check the contents of the Gradle layered JAR with `java -Djarmode=layertools -jar build/libs/*.jar list`... because with Gradle I get a `spring-boot-loader` folder... which seems to not be the case with maven... equally the `resources` folder does not exist in the Gradle plugin's layered Jar.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation is available for how to activate the layered fat jar for spring boot applications with the spring-boot-gradle-plugin.

See the details at [Packaging Layered Jars with Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.M1/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-layered-jars).

In the `build.gradle` file:

```
// Groovy solution
bootJar {
    layered()
}


// Kotlin solution
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    layered()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A slightly more concise version of the Kotlin version is `tasks.bootJar{layered()}`

Comment: This is what you need in case you're writing a groovy plugin: `project.tasks.withType(BootJar).first().layered.includeLayerTools = true`

Answer (score 4):

You can also find more information in here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-layered-jars

```
bootJar {
  layered {
    enabled = true

    application {
      intoLayer("spring-boot-loader") {
        include "org/springframework/boot/loader/**"
      }
      intoLayer("application")
    }
    
    dependencies {
      intoLayer("snapshot-dependencies") {
        include "*:*:*SNAPSHOT"
      }
      intoLayer("dependencies")
    }

    layerOrder = ["dependencies", "spring-boot-loader", "snapshot-dependencies", "application"]
  }
}
```

You will find corresponding layer names in `layers.idx` file inside you JAR.