# How to turn on layering of build pack generated docker image in Spring Boot, using the the gradle plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, buildpack, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

In this [video](https://youtu.be/WL7U-yGfUXA?t=480), Phil Webb describes how to turn on layering of a Spring Boot docker image built by build packs, by adding the layers enabled true configuration for the maven plugin. How do you configure the gradle plugin to do the same ? I can't see any reference to this in the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#build-image) for the gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you configure the bootRun task, not the bootBuildImage task, like so:

```
tasks.bootJar {
  layered()
}
```

My question ended up being a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288194/spring-layered-fat-jar-and-gradle-plugin-layertools-jarmode)